# select <option> text invisible before on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm experiencing a weird visual issue with `<select>` `<option>` elements. I have a function which runs every time a specific `<option>` is chosen from a `<select>` dropdown, this code then sets one of the options of a select element to be selected, this is happening via:

```
$('select[name="data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]"]').find('option[value=""]').attr('selected', true)
```

The select that gets a value selected is:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="EmpIndustry" name="data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]" aria-describedby="EmployerIndustryHelp" required>
  <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
  <option value="10">Health</option>
  <option value="22">Retail</option>
</select>
```

However, the text of the select is invisible, despite there being valid options in the menu.

[image]
[image]

Any idea why?

REPRODUCTION URL: https://codepen.io/sts-ryan-holton/pen/LKJbzL

Comment: could you create a reproducible demo of the issue?

Comment: It looks like you're using a library which replaces the UI of the standard `select` control. My assumption would be the issue is there, however we'd need to see more of your code (ideally in a snippet) to confirm that. Also note that your first line of JS can be simplified to just `$('#EmpIndustry').val('')`

Comment: More simplified  - `$("#EmpIndustry").val('')`

Comment: Here's a reproduction URL: https://codepen.io/sts-ryan-holton/pen/LKJbzL, please change the initial select at the top to disability benefits, and back to full time employment @Manav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code.

```
$('select[name="data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]"]').find('option[value=""]').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: I don't see how this solved anything given that the outcome is the same as `attr()`, although this is better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with:

```
$('select[name="data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]"]').val(25)
```

When you are moving between industries you are resetting the selected value to '25'. but the value of your 'Please Select' is "" (empty string).  In your fiddle I changed that line to:

```
$('select[name="data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]"]').val("")
```

And now when I switch it is correctly displaying Please Select.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anyone of below code

1. $('select[name="data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]"]').find('option[value=""]').prop('selected', true);
2. $('select[name="data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]"] option[value=""]').prop('selected', true);
3. $('select[name="data[ApplicationPayday][EmpIndustry]"]').val('');

**Since select option has id and id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element, above code can be written like....**

1. $('#EmpIndustry').find('option[value=""]').prop('selected', true);
2. $('#EmpIndustry option[value=""]').prop('selected', true);
3. $('#EmpIndustry').val(''); (code is same as ravibagul91 )